# правильное использование product от schema.org

Tags: seo, microdata

[имеем](https://schema.org/Product) и еще есть желание применить данное чудо. нужно объяснить 1 момент. Во всех примерах приведен код MICRODATA/RDFa/JSON-LD

И у меня вопрос, их все 3 надо вписать в текст или достаточно 1 из методов?

если все 3 сразу, то где пример такого чуда?
если 1 то какой использовать?

Comment: Достаточно один, выбирайте на свой вкус. Если вас интересует индексация поисковиками, читайте документацию к интересующим вас поисковикам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один. Google рекомендует `JSON-LD`, но может совпадение, а может и нет, но `RDF` быстрее индексируется.